# Tensorial product, a simple question

Tags: tensor-products, classical-mechanics

I need to find the components of $D$:

$$D=a\otimes a$$

where $a$ is a tensor of order 2.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a "tensor of order 2"?

Comment: The representation of a tensor o order 2 is a matriz of order $3\times 3$.

Comment: Okay, I got a bit confused with the terminology. (I am used to thinking of tensors of having a type $(n,m)$.) So $D$ should be a tensor of order 4, and its components are the products of the components of $a$. So if $a_{ij}$ are the components of $a$, then the components of $D$ should be $a_{ij}a_{kl}$, where $i,j,k,l$ are indices that range from $1$ to $3$.

Comment: May be the question is wrong :/

Comment: Is my answer not what you were expecting / looking for?